# what is defined behavior of group by column name and number in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

when exucute the sql statement list below in mysql, there is only one row returned. And I looked up the mysql document and didn't find the defined behavior of the statement. Is there any syntax error in this statement?

```
 select * from Deal group by id and 1;
```

Demo on [sqlfriddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6dae5/2/0)

Comment: I finally found a link about  `group by` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at what happens when you use the following:

```
select *, id and 1 as newCol from Deal
```

- [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6dae5/4)

`newCol` equals 1 for each row.  That's because `mysql` evaluates that as a boolean.  This explains why you only return a single result with `group by`, you are grouping by the same value in every record.

---

Perhaps you are wondering what happens when you group by a number with a comma instead of using `and`:

```
select * from Deal group by id, 2
```

- [More fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6dae5/5)

That groups by both the `id` and the second field in your table (`price`).